# lowdb .find not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I have an extremely simple local api that I am using to test out a mobile application I am building, but I can't get lowdb to find the record in the database correctly. I have tried using .find() and .filter(), but both are returning undefined. It is an extremely simple setup. I have a route that picks up a post request, gets the mobile_pin from the request body, then should be returning the id of the entry in the database based on the mobile_pin, but it is always undefined. Here is the node function that isn't working...

```
router.post('/connect', function(req, res, next) {
  const db = res.locals.db;
  const mobile_pin = req.body.mobile_pin;
  console.log(db.get('users').value());
  console.log("Looking for mobile_code: " + mobile_pin);
  let entry = db.get('users').find({mobile_code: mobile_pin}).value();
  console.log(entry);
});
```

I know there is no res.writeHead or anyhting, since it isn't working I didn't write that part, I am using the console to view the data. The console output...

> [{ id: "UUID", mobile_code: 775902, posts: [], date: [],
>   modified_timestamp: []}]
>
> Looking for mobile_code: 775902
>
> undefined

The entry is obviously in the database, in fact it is the only entry there at the moment, but it is always undefined when I try to get the entry based on the mobile_code. I have tried using both .find() and using .filter(), but both of them log undefined in the console. Is there no way to get that entry based on the mobile_code? The documentation shows that .find() should give me that entry. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason. When making a post request the mobile_pin is converted to a string, so there was no entry with the mobile_code "775902". You have to use parseInt(req.body.mobile_pin); or the database will not be able to find the entry.